# Redeeming physical bitcoin and transfer from mini private key to my wallet

Tags: private-key

How do I send bitcoin from physical bitcoin private key to my wallet address?

I can't seem to find an option to receive payment from a 30 byte mini private key and the only thing close is to get from a qt code which opens camera.

Answer (score 1):

Import it into a Blockchain.info wallet.

Or use the python script from: http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mini_private_key_format#Decoding